# AttributeError: module 'random' has no attribute 'choise' Django

Tags: python, django

Never mind.. I was writing choice with an 's' instead of an 'c' .... :(

so i'm kinda new to this world of programming and I took the Udemy course called Python and Django Full Stack Web Developer.
Now i'm on the last part where we are using Django.
I watched the video and followed his code and tried to run it bymyself.
But then I encountered by this error.
I looked after a solution online and in here also, but I saw solution that offer to check if there is another function or module with the same name by mistake or something, and I have not..
this is my code:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choise(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("populating script!")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")


and I refer to the models.py code also:

import os
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')

import django
django.setup()

import random
from first_app.models import AccessRecord, Webpage, Topic
from faker import Faker

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']

def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choise(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t

def populate(N=5):
    for entry in range(N):
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        webpg.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]

        acc_rec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("populating script!")
    populate(20)
    print("populating complete!")



HELP PLEASE :)
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo in this function, here is the correct version.

```
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
```

Comment: he already said as much in the first sentence of the question

Answer (score 1):

It is a simple spelling error you have made it is supposed to be `random.choice` not `random.choise`

Comment: he already said as much in the first sentence of the question

Comment: I hadn't noticed until I answered

Comment: Yeah thank you, just realized it after I posted.. Hate when this happens ..

Answer (score 1):

you have a typing mistake in your code. It must be `random.choice()` in the 15th line. That's the right function:

```
def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t
```

Hope I could help you.

Comment: He already figured it out in the first sentence of his question. You should flag these kinds of questions

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice. But in his question he asked why this error occurred (the error in the title). That's the simple answer.

Comment: Yeah thank you, just realized it after I posted.. Hate when this happens ..